# What's this type of switch called?

Tags: switches

What is the exact name of this type of switch?

[image]

[image]

It comes from a digital piano sustain pedal. Most of these cheap sustain pedals seem to use the same size switch. I'd like to replace this particular switch due to unwanted noise when in use.

Comment: have you tried cleaning the switch contacts?

Comment: I should have explained that by unwanted noise I mean that the mechanical movement of the switch causes an annoying clicking sound. I was hoping to replace the switch (rather than the whole pedal) with a better quality part. I've had a couple of similar pedals in the past that used the same type of switch but they didn't produce this noise.

Comment: @jsotola That looks as if it could be a one-way trip. trying to get that switch apart and back together is more likely to destroy it IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suitable replacement.

It's known as a DPDT momentary push switch (Pushbutton Switch DPDT Momentary Through Hole, Right Angle).

[image]

Comment: It's not the same as a guitar pedal stomp switch, which is a different size and usually latching/maintained. The metal knob on those switches protrudes out of the casing of the pedal and is pressed with your foot. The switches in these sustain pedals are always momentary and your foot pushes a metal lever down onto the switch. I thought it might be a commonly used part and therefore easy to replace, but I've not been able to find anything of the exact same type anywhere.

Comment: I got it. My answer has been duly edited.

Comment: Thanks! With that info info I've been able to find what looks like the exact switch I need for sale from various sellers on Ebay. Cheers.

Comment: Anytime! I'm glad you found it useful.